# How to catch and rethrow an exception

Tags: exception, clojure

I have a clojure function which calls another function to update the database.

```
(^{PUT true
       Path "/{id}"
       Produces ["application/json"]
       Consumes ["application/json"]
       ApiOperation {:value "Update" :notes ""}}
       updateFeedback [this
                       ^{PathParam "id"} id
                       body]
       (require 'com.xx.x.xx.xx.xx-response)
       (let [doc (json/read-json body)]
         (if-let [valid-doc (validate doc)]
                 (try+
                  (->>
                   (assoc valid-doc :modificationDate (Utilities/getCurrentDate))
                   (couch/update-document dbs/xx-db)
                   (core/ok-response))
                  (catch java.io.IOException ex
                         (log/error "line num 197"))
                  (catch java.lang.Exception ex
                         (log/error "line num 200"))))))
```

The update-document function throws an exception. I would like to throw it back to the caller -- in this case updateFeedback so that the content in the catch block gets executed. For some reason, clojure logs the exception and the catch block in the caller never executes.

To verify I wrapped the code in the update-document function in a try catch block. There the catch block got executed.

How do I add a throws clause to the function?

Update: I have updated the function. Apologies for the syntax issues. I have updated the code we are using. I am not familiar with clojure. This is a code which we inherited and we are asked to fix a bug. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: `do-stuff` is not a valid function - you are missing the argument declaration, and you have mismatched parentheses.

Comment: Your 'some-function' mostly probably doesn't throw the exception. If it did the catch block would be executed as you would like. Check your 'some-function'. Could you execute it in repl? What does it return ?

Comment: I reformatted this example without changing any of the meaning. and changed the title to match the question better

Answer (score 13):

If you are trying to catch and then re-throw an exception you can do something like this:

```
(defn throwing-function
  []
  (/ 7 0))

(defn catching-function
  []
  (try
    (throwing-function)
    (catch Exception e
      (println "Caught exception:" e)
      (println "Re-throwing ...")
      (throw e))))
```